# Entity Relations in Services

Tags: oop, jpa, design-patterns, entity, spring-rest

I have such model relations: **User**, **Task**, each user can create his own tasks and can see **All** tasks. So obviously I'll have **TaskService** with methods **getAllTasks()**, **getSortedTasks(String value)**, etc.
I'm confused where should I have **createTask(Task task)**, **updateTask(lond id, Task task)** methods - in **TaskService** or in **UserService**, because I'm told I should have REST API looks like:

rather

```
post users/{id}/tasks
```

than

```
post /tasks
```

because "a *task* belongs to a particular *user*". So I can't choose between separate *services,api* for each entity and common *services,api* whre **User** is relations owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the endpoint for creating tasks in a task resource.

Both is possible:

**POST your_root.com/api/{userId}/tasks/**  ----> Creates task and takes the value of the creator from the uri.

But you could also go this way:

**POST your_root.com/api/tasks/**  ---> In this case you have to tell the server by JSON or XML who created the task. The body could look like this i.E.:

```
{

  "author": "user A",
  "assingee": null,
  "headline": "Login Page for my app",
  "text":"Build fancy login page"

}
```

Last variant and my preferred:

**POST your_root.com/api/{userId}/tasks/**
and the authorId in the body again:

```
{

  "authorId":"12"
  "author": "user A",
  "assingee": null,
  "headline": "Login Page for my app",
  "text":"Build fancy login page"

}
```

The advantage of the last variant is that you can check whether the userId in the uri equals the authorId of the body. So you can avoid that this request with a certain Id is made by accident.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. So, in the last case should I have 'createUserTask(id,  task)' in UserService too or I could use TaskService in UserRestController ?? I don't really understand OOP principles in "Service-Entity' case. Could you help me with that please?

Comment: All services that create a task are part of the task service. Don't be confused by the relation to user. You have to create the task by the taskservice. The taskservice has also to check whether the user exists. Is this true then the service creates the task. Otherwise your service will respond with 404 - User not found.